# What happens to local Realm DB when app is auto offloaded by iOS for lack of recent usage?

Tags: ios, realm

In iOS 11, unused apps have the potential to be automatically removed by the operating system to conserve disk space.

This is hard to test because I would need to let an app in development sit unused on a device for an extended period of time.

No similar questions were found online or addressed in relevant documentation.

What will happen to any application data persisted in a Realm DB? From the OS point of view are any underlying data saved such as a Realm DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the app offload feature is that the app itself is removed whilst any data is left in situ. The option on iPad settings specifically states that "Your documents and data will be saved". If you look under storage for your app on an installed device, it will differentiate between "App size" and "Documents & Data", so only "App size" should be recovered by offloading.

If you have the app already published in the app store and installed on a device then you can test this (not sure if it works under TestFlight). Under the Settings -> iPhone/iPad Storage, if you select the app then you have the option to Offload the app manually. Opening the app redownloaded it from the app store, and my data was still available from the realm storage before the data refreshed.